# Laravel 5 Auth: These credentials do not match our records

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-5

I'm just starting out with Laravel 5, I come from Laravel 4 environment so it shouldn't be too hard.

I heard L5 comes with a built-in authentication system which is neat.
I've set everything up from database to views.

The registration process is working correctly and after that it logs me in automatically. but when I log out and try to log back in, I get this error:

> These credentials do not match our records.

I'm not sure what's wrong. do I have to write the login controller manually or how does it work in L5?

Comment: Most likely, you simply enter wrong password or email. Try to register again.

Comment: Are you properly hashing the password? `Auth::attempt()`expects it to be hashed.

Comment: In my case I've got this error when created User and passed to it `password` as `$request->password` but that **$request** amid gathered form names had different password's `name`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same issue. The reason for mine was that
I defined `setPasswordAttribute` in my `User` model so every time, I enter plain password, it hashes before sending to DB.

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = \Hash::make($password);
}
```

and in my db:seed, I was creating a user with hashed password with `Hash::make("password")`, too. So laravel hashes hashed password :)

In laravel version 5.* you don't need to hash input password for Auth, because Auth manages it itself. you just have to pass `{{csrf_field()}}` through form.

Comment: Now >=5.1 you can use `bcrypt($password)` too

Answer (score 9):

In addition to **@mervasdayi** solution, a good way to hash passwords in `setPasswordAttribute` avoiding rehashing problems could be this:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password){
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::needsRehash($password) ? Hash::make($password) : $password;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Further to what @mervasdayi & Gerard Reches have suggested. Just thought I'd make a note that you will need to include

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
```

at the top of your `User` model when adding in these fixes.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it is later but i found two solutions to solve this problem.
Firstly you can use bcrypt function if you use laravel 5.3. Look at the below function. It means that your get your data in array.

```
public function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Secondly you can use mutator to fix it like this:

```
 public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = \Hash::make($password);
}
```

Hope that it can help others. Best regards

Comment: I am getting similar error on laravel 8. Any idea what could be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I attempt too many times with the wrong password, and then I am unable to login with the user for some hour, and at the same time, I am able to log in with other users.