# Laravel - Moved project now can't login

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have an existing Laravel 5.6 project, I have moved it over to a new Bitnami WAMP installation.

I have migrated the database and seeded it so it contains my user account, but whenever I attempt to log in I get the following error..

```
these credentials do not match our records
```

I have confirmed the password is correct and that it can access the database, is there anything else I should be checking?

I am leaning towards it being a configuration issue with the Bitnami install but am slightly lost on where to be checking.

Comment: Did you copy across the same application key?

Comment: do you create a pasword in the seed file like this `Hash::make("password")` ?

Comment: Application key has been copied over, have also made sure the password is correctly hashed

Comment: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30467942/4881811) it may help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Change .env file, DB name, DB user name And DB Password

```
composer update
php artisan key:generate
```